# How to give file permissions

Tags: file-permissions

How to give file permissions while uploading my code `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can give file permission like

```
$fp = fopen($file, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
    chmod($file, 0777);  //changed to add the zero
```

> chmod ("/yourdir/yourfile", 0777);

get the reference from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_chmod.asp)

Comment: Thanks for comment Rohit but when i download file i am getting error of file Failed - Server problem like ths. and for download i have used code like this <a  href='.$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/demo/uploads/".$row["invoicefile"].' download>Download</a>

Comment: File permission server its 777 only Rohit

Comment: double check file is exist at $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/demo/uploads/".$row["invoicefile"] or not?
and maybe you have not enough permission to demo or uploads folder, just try directly in url to open your file

Comment: Thanks for reply Rohit i got this error when i directly open by url error Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.